# Check for bool in numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

i got a little problem.
I want to check every element of a numpy array of dtype 'Array of object', if there are any values==NaN. The col of Name is not supposed to be checked
If the value is NaN then the function sets this value to zero.
I get an an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is my array:

```
Name    Watt    Fluenz  
A1C1    10  nan
A1C2    20  nan
A1C3    30  nan
```

This is my function:

```
def check_NaN(arr):
    [row, col] = arr.shape
    for i in range(col):
        if arr[i] == 'Name':
            continue
        elif arr[i] == 'name':
            continue
        else:
            for j in range(row):    
                if arr[i][j].isnan():
                    arr[i][j] = 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need `pandas`, as you are working with 2-d data.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Then, you can easily check

```
>>> df['Fluenz'].isnull()
```

and it will return an iterable of `True`s and `False`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_NaN(arr):
    [row, col] = arr.shape
    for i in range(col):
        if 'Name' in arr[:,i]:
            continue
        elif 'name' in arr[:,i]:
            continue
        else:
            for j in range(1,row):
                if arr[j][i].dtype == object and np.isnan(arr[j][i]):
                    arr[j][i] = 0
```

Mistakes:

1. Comparison of whole 1D array with string "Name" / "name"
2. Accessing indexes out of bound by using `arr[i][j]` instead of `arr[j][i]`
3. "If" condition for checking is "nan" was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, the reason, why I check the whole array is that I dont know on which position of the array the 'Name' could be found. In this simple case it is a position 0.

Comment: ok, I have edited the code so that string can be searched in column in a right way. Please accept the answer if you found it correct. Thanks.